# Can single user have multiple roles in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-platform, layer-control

Is it possible to assign multiple roles to a single user?

I would like to have the following setup:

- Role A gives edit/view access to layer A
- Role B gives edit/view access to layer B

and

- User X has Role A and Role B
- User Z has Role A
- User Q has Role B

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused qurstion/Best answer model operates. You've pretty much described IT-wide best practice, and what the the documentation recommends, so yes, it's possible. The particulars depend on details not provided, so the question isn't really answerable.

Comment: You had a tag for ArcGIS Server but make no mention of it in your question body. Are you using it?

Comment: @Vince what details am I not providing? You say that this is recommended in the documentation. Could you please provide a link to the documentation. I have been unable to find any mention of assigning multiple roles to a single user in the documentation

Comment: "ArcGIS" is a large platform with access protocols at each level. The details missing are the software in use, the steps you have taken, and the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [assigning users to groups](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/manage-groups.htm). Each group can have specific permissions, and each person can be a part of multiple groups. So you could make a group with Role A permissions and a group with Role B permissions, and assign Users X, Z, and Q accordingly. You might also want to take a look at more [general user types](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/roles.htm), such as Viewer vs. Publisher which could be useful when designing group permissions. These links are for ArcGIS Enterprise, but similar concepts exist across all different parts of the ArcGIS platform.